# Eight digit numbers stored as text--how to convert them to dates? Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a built-in way to convert eight digit numbers ex. 04102000 or 10232005 to a date type in Excel?  Right clicking on format cells and then choosing date doesn't work.  If I convert them to numbers first and then convert to date some crazy stuff happens.  Anyone know a good method to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They must be stored as text rather than numbers to allow there to be a leading zero, if you just want a quick manual way;

Select the cells, *Data*->*Text to Columns* skip the steps that ask about delimiters & pick *Date - MDY* from the format options.

Answer (score 2):

Treat them as digit strings rather than numbers:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2))
```

Replacing `A1` with your required cell reference.