# Excel: How to format a 10 digit number into date time

Tags: excel

I have a number like so 2016031802 and I want it to show up as 2016/03/18 2:00 so that I can use it in a graph of something/time where time is incremented hourly. How can I go about formatting this number so that it shows up in date time format?

I am using Excel 2011.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087787/how-do-i-convert-a-given-number-into-time-format-hhmmss-in-vba

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214771/eight-digit-numbers-stored-as-text-how-to-convert-them-to-dates-excel?rq=1 would be closer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))+TIME(RIGHT(A1,2),0,0)
```

Then format the cells with a custom format of:

```
yyyy/mm/dd h:mm
```